# How do I develop efficiently with Spark? After I edit code and package, spark-submit is too slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jvm

My current development cycle is to edit code locally in IntelliJ, have it packaged into a jar automatically using `sbt ~ package`, which is then copied automatically to the cluster master node with an `rsync` command in a loop. That's all lovely and streamlined but then when I run `spark-submit` I have to wait about 10 to 20 seconds before I even start to see the output of my code. This is a horribly slow way to do things if I want to constantly test the results of small changes.

Is there a way to reuse the JVM, SparkContext, etc. so that I don't have to wait while `spark-submit` restarts everything from scratch? I'm using YARN.

Comment: 10-20 seconds? I wish Scala compiled my code in that time!

Comment: @JishnuPrathap this is about my personal productivity and having an enjoyable workflow, not code performance. Waiting 15 seconds every time I run a script (often just to see an exception because I made a typo or something) is very annoying.

Comment: @AlexHall at dev env u dont have to use Spark-Submit , you could use local mode if you are not using a spark-cluster

Comment: Are all your spark dependencies are compiled to a jar and uploaded in separate to the cluster?

Comment: @lev no, spark-submit provides those dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the best solution was to run the scala spark shell and use `:load` on a script which I continuously `rsync`ed from my local machine.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you do your development in local-mode, and only run on the cluster when you have something more complete and ready to test?

You can create a local Spark context with

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("App")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: Because the work I'm doing is timing how long it takes the cluster, with all its resources, to process a large file.

Comment: Fair enough, that is unfortunate and I don't think there's a perfect answer to your problem. You could try using Spark Shell and dealing with Spark interactively, giving you the chance to do different iterations within a single Spark shell session?

Comment: I'm actually experimenting with that, will post an answer if I'm happy with it after a while.

Comment: But at least you'd see that exception from the typo you made quicker.  Presumably processing a large file takes significant time compared to 10 or 20 seconds (or it wouldn't be a large file)